# Addy Osmanis pub/sub, trouble understanding the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, publish-subscribe

I am using Addy Osmani's pub sub method:

```
var topics = {};

jQuery.Topic = function( id ) {
    var callbacks,
        topic = id && topics[ id ];
    if ( !topic ) {
        callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();
        topic = {
            publish: callbacks.fire,
            subscribe: callbacks.add,
            unsubscribe: callbacks.remove
        };
        if ( id ) {
            topics[ id ] = topic;
        }
    }
    return topic;
};
```

but before I add it to my project I'd like to understand it a little better.  It's fairly simple except for one line I've never seen:  `topic = id && topics[ id ];`

`topic = id` ok.   What is the && operator doing here?  is it adding id to the topics array? or making a comparison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
topic = id && topics[ id ];
```

should be read as

```
topic = (id && topics[ id ]);
```

`&&` has an higher precedence, as stated on [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

The value assigned to `topic` is `topic[id]` when `id` is evaluated as "true" value, `false` otherwise: so this is a shorter way for

```
if (id) {
   topic = topics[id];
}
else {
   topic = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is an example for Pub/Sub on the jQuery documenation page for jQuery.Callbacks().
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/

I've written a summary of what this example does, which to me, was not immediately apparent.

---

Topic() is a function that returns a topic object containing three renamed function objects:
callbacks.fire, callbacks.add, callbacks.remove.

topic object contains the three function objects, renamed to publish, subscribe, unsubscribe

id refers to unique string identifying the pubSub channel:  for example:  "mailArrived", "mailSent"

topics object (plural) contains topic objects, keyed by id. It is used to determine if a topic object with that id exists.

Topic() checks if the id is not false (undefined, null, NaN, 0, "", or false).

If id is true, and a topic for that id exists in topics,
then topic object is assigned topics[id] and returned.

If id is true, and a topic for that id does not exist in topics,
then a new topic object is created, placed in topics as topics[id] and returned.

If id is false, a new topic object is created and returned, but not put in topics.

Each time a topic object is created, a closure is created over the unique value of a new jQuery callbacks list.